# how to get the system-date using cql query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I want to retrieve those data which belongs to today's date, i tried below thing

```
select * from tablename where fieldname = dateof(now());
```

This query gives date and system-time both, so result will not be proper.

How can I get only current(today's) date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question the column family tablename is using the timestamp fieldname as primary key. In that case, each row is identified by the timestamp and not the date so you can not query by the date.

Based on this, you have to change your data model to define the primary key on another way. A possibility is use a table like created like this:

```
USE test;

create table posts(username varchar, 
    time timeuuid, 
    post_text varchar, 
    primary key(username, time)
);

insert into posts(username, time, post_text) 
values ('me', now(), 'Example');

insert into posts(username, time, post_text) 
values ('me', now(), 'Example');

select username, dateOf(time), post_text from posts;
```

In this case you obtain two results like this

[image]

So if you want to query on a specific date you can use:

select username, 
dateOf(time), 
post_text 
from posts 
where time >= minTimeuuid('2014-04-23 00:00') 
and time < minTimeuuid('2014-04-24 00:00') 
and username = 'me';

---

Sources:

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#usingdates

http://christopher-batey.blogspot.nl/2013/05/time-series-based-queries-in-cassandra.html

Comment: sliglty i changed the data in insert statement 
values ('me', now(), 'Example');
values ('me1', now(), 'Example1');

and executed last query something like 

select username, dateOf(time), post_text from posts where time >= minTimeuuid('2014-04-23 00:00') and time < minTimeuuid('2014-04-24 00:00'); 

and it is giving me 
Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and th
us may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite
 the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING..

can you tell me the reason or how to solve this?

Comment: The reason is you are trying to filter using only part of the primary key and that is considered a potentially expensive query. You can still query using something like: select username, dateOf(time), post_text from posts 
where time >= minTimeuuid('2014-04-23 00:00') 
and time < minTimeuuid('2014-04-24 00:00') LIMIT 10 ALLOW FILTERING;  
You can check the documentation here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html

Comment: got it.. Appreciate your help.